# Multiple scroll function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would need a jQuery solution for a multiple scroll function. Generally, I imagine something like [multiscroll.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/) does, but it should work with more than two columns.

This is how the basic layout could look like:

```js
$("column:nth-child(2n+1)").css("scroll", "otherDirection");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">

  <div class="column">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="column">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="column">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="column">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="column">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

How can every second column scroll to top while the others scroll down while scrolling in this area? Would be very thankful for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not the best at css so I'm sure someone can come up with a better solution than this but hopefully, it will give you a starting point

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}


/* column layout */

.columns {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  display: flex;
  height: 110vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.column div {
  animation: slideDown 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, calc(-100% + 100vh), 0);
  }
}

.column-reverse div {
  animation: slideUp 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, calc(100% - 100vh), 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://flackr.github.io/scroll-timeline/dist/scroll-timeline.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="columns" data-scroll-container="">

  <div class="column column-reverse">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="column b">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="column column-reverse">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="column b">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="column column-reverse">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your after?

```js
// Fallback for browsers that don't support CSS ScrollTimeline
if (!CSS.supports("animation-timeline: foo")) {
  // As we're about to shift content out of .columns, we need it to hide its overflow
  document.querySelector(".columns").style.overflowY = "hidden";

  // Set up timeline
  const timeline = new ScrollTimeline({
    scrollSource: document.documentElement,
    timeRange: 1,
    fill: "both"
  });

  // Loop all eligible columns
  document.querySelectorAll(".column-reverse").forEach(($column) => {
    // Flip item order in reverse columns
    $column.style.flexDirection = "column-reverse";

    // Hook Animation
    $column.animate({
      transform: [
        "translateY(calc(-100% + 100vh))",
        "translateY(calc(100% - 100vh))"
      ]
    }, {
      duration: 1,
      fill: "both",
      timeline
    });
  });
}
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#columns {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}


/* column layout */

.columns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 80em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}


/* Inside one column, lay out all items in column direction */

.column {
  --column-offset: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: var(--column-offset) 0;
}


/* Limit site of the images */

.column__item-imgwrap img {
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 0.75;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.column__item-caption {
  text-align: center;
}
  
/* Scroll-Timeline Supported, Yay! */

@supports (animation-timeline: works) {
  /* Hide Warning */
  .warning {
    display: none;
  }
  /* As we're about to shift content out of .columns, we need it to hide its overflow */
  .columns {
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  .column-reverse {
    /* Flip item order in reverse columns */
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  /* Set up Animation */
  @keyframes adjust-position {
    /* Start position: shift entire column up, but not so that it goes out of view */
    from {
      transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 100vh));
    }
    /* End position: shift entire column down, but not so that it goes out of view */
    to {
      transform: translateY(calc(100% - 100vh));
    }
  }
  /* Set up scroll-timeline */
  @scroll-timeline scroll-in-document {
    source: auto;
    /* Default scroll-timeline: scrolling in the document */
  }
  /* Hook our animation with the timeline to our columns */
  .column-reverse {
    animation: 1s adjust-position linear forwards;
    animation-timeline: scroll-in-document;
  }
}

/* general styles */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://flackr.github.io/scroll-timeline/dist/scroll-timeline.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="columns" data-scroll-container="">

  <div class="column column-reverse">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="column">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="column column-reverse">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="column">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="column column-reverse">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: scrolling those cats is hypnotic...

Comment: haha yes indeed

Comment: Ohh, I think it's very nice! But what must be added to get an infinite scroll in both directions?